# How to get a value in the jQuery, that is sent from the node js server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

In the node.js server, I sent a value in json format and need to put that in a javascript variable. I send the value like

```
res.render('/path/', {
    testVal: 'testVal'
});
```

In the handlebars I can get it by

```
{{testVal}}
```

Now I want to get it in a javascript variable in the client side. Like in jQuery

```
window.onload = function() {
        if (window.jQuery) {
            // jQuery is loaded
            var test = testVal;
            alert(test);
        }
    }
```

How to get the testVal in the test variable?

Comment: Are you trying to do that inside your jade file

Comment: I'm using handlebars and tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using **jquery** in the same file the data is rendered then you can do something like this :

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.jQuery) {
        // jQuery is loaded
        var test = "{{ testVal }}";
        alert(test);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Ryad, how about if the javascript code is in a separate JS file? How would we access the variable there in js file?